# GridView Highlight selected Item

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am using custom background for Grid items, and as normal it works, but when i do click on any of the Grid item (it's not working)

So what could be the reason, why its not working when i am doing click on any of the Grid Item, whereas its working in normal mode..

For ImageGallery I am using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) tutorial and to highlight grid item following [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />

</selector>
```

Grid item layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/grid_background"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the main grid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <!-- The GridView to display picture's preview  -->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"       
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        > 
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what i am getting as normal and even when i do tap on any of the GridView Item:

[image]

Comment: Remove background and try selector in 'android:listSelector' in Gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you
make your selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />

</selector>
```

and Relative layout add

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
     android:background="@drawable/grid_background"
     android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line  android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: addd this line to  Relative layout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: can you try my answer @Oreo

Comment: android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"

add this in your gridview  tag

Answer (score 2):

Write drawable file for your selector like this call it selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then inside xml of gridview add following two lines

```
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
 android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: color disappears when finger is lifted from the grid item